# Javascript equivalent of Java Regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to write a javascript REGEX to validate a string.

It should validate to the requirement which is as follow.

it should have only Uppercase and lowercase English letters (a to z, A to Z) (ASCII: 65 to 90, 97 to 122) AND/OR Digits 0 to 9 (ASCII: 48 to 57) AND Characters - _ ~ (ASCII: 45, 95, 126). Provided that they are not the first or last character. It can also have Character. (dot, period, full stop) (ASCII: 46) Provided that it is not the first or last character, and provided also that it does not appear two or more times consecutively.

I have a Java version of the REGEX as following.

> ^(?=[^\W_])[\w~-]++(\.[\w*~-]++)*+(?<=[^\W_])$

And unsuccessfully trying to convert it be used with Javascript. Below is my failed attempt.

> ^(?=[^\W_])[\w~-]+(.[\w~-]+)*(.*[\w])$

it fails on the follow two tests

`abc..def
1`

Test cases for invalid strings:

`"a."
"1."
"a1."
"aB78."
"aB78..ab"
"aB78,1"
"aB78 abc"
".Abc12"`

Test cases for valid strings:

`"a"
"1"
"a1"
"a.1"
"abc-def"
"a1b2c~3"
"012_345"`

Comment: js regex is mostly the same as any other regex. what have you tried?

Comment: **What** did you try to convert it to JS? Show us your unsuccessful attempt!

Comment: it may be easier to use non-capturing group `?:`

Comment: `^(?=[^\W_])[\w~-]+(\.[\w~-]+)*(.*[a-zA-Z0-9])$` is my unsuccessful attempt. It failes on the `abc...def`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your requirements, you could come up with:

```
^(?!.*\.{2})(?=.*[a-zA-Z0-9]$)[a-zA-Z0-9][-~.\w]*$
```

In `multiline` mode, see [a demo on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/aU4aR4/4).

**Explanation:**

- **^**                  assure it's the beginning of the line
- **(?!.*.{2,})**       negative lookahead - no two dots consecutively
- **(?=.*[a-zA-Z0-9]$)** the last character needs to be one of these
- **[a-zA-Z0-9]**  first character needs to be one of these
- **[-~.\w]***     anything of these afterwards (zero or more times)
- **$**            assure the string ends here

Comment: This works perfectly. Thank you for taking time to explain the regex as well.

Comment: The expression fails for a single character and 2 character string. e.g
`a
1
a1
1a`

Comment: @AGilani: Please clarify your requirements then and let's see what we can do.

Comment: Please accept apologies for not asking the question in full details. Just added new items to passing and failing test scenarios. Appreciate your help.

Comment: @AGilani: Updated the answer, see regex demo. Using multiple lookaheads now.

Answer (score 2):

There are no lookbehinds in JavaScript regexes. Fortunately, you didn't need it in your case anyway. Replace

```
(?<=[^\W_])
```

With just

```
[^\W_]
```

Comment: i came to the same conclusion and rewrote it as follow `^(?=[^\W_])[\w~-]+(\.[\w~-]+)*(.*[a-zA-Z0-9])$`